# Show all constructor overloads

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, when I start typing a class name, it shows the possible constructors:

[image]

Now, imagine I decided to go with the first constructor, only passing in context:
[image]

Now I again need to see which constructors are available. How can I now display all possible constructor overloads without first deleting the `context` parameter?

Comment: move the cursor before `context` and try

Comment: Doesn't `Control + P` / `Command + P` work?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> it will show the popup again ...

[image]